# How to dynamically update a value inside the string for req.write('{ "upc":"make-this-dynamic"}')?

Tags: javascript

MY problem is using the API that uses req.write('{ "upc":"604214384507"}') to look up an item- I cannot get it to populate with dynamic values outside of the string, it seems to be messing with the syntax that the API requires. Is there a syntax I could use to preserve API needed format but use a dynamic variable to fill out the upc number?

```
let UPC = 604214384507
req.write(`'{ "upc":"${UPC}"}'`)

results in undefined


const https = require('https')
var opts = {
hostname: 'api.upcitemdb.com',
path: '/prod/trial/lookup',
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",

 }
}
var req = https.request(opts, function (res) {
console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
console.log('headers: ', res.headers);
res.on('data', function (UPCoutput) {
    var UPCparsed = JSON.parse(UPCoutput);
    console.log('Product: ' + UPCparsed.items[0].title);
    console.log('UPC: ' + UPCparsed.items[0].upc);
    console.log('Image: ' + UPCparsed.items[0].images[0]);
    console.log('Price: ' + UPCparsed.items[0].offers[0].price);

 })
})
req.on('error', function (e) {
console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write('{ "upc":"604214384507"}')
req.end()
```

I expect to be able to dynamically feed the UPC number to the API to pull data.

Answer (score 0):

So just write that like you did earlier:

```
req.write(`{ "upc": "${UPC}" }`);
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does not incorporate ' around {}- I ended up using JSON.strigify

Comment: I know @zero2hero - that's the second time you've told me, and I saw your answer.

Comment: thank you! Sorry, I am newbie and I deleted my original comments by accident! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use JSON.strigify

```
const userUPC = "604214384507"
const searchAPI = { upc: userUPC }
JSON.stringify(UPC)
req.write(JSON.stringify(searchAPI))
req.end()
```